# Difference between a python dictionary object and what json.loads return

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a question about the difference between a plain Python dictionary object and what is returned as output of json.loads(str). As per checking type() on both the objects, it says dict. But i want to confirm this if json.load() actually returns a plain dict or a json object which is in dictionary format.
My code is as below :

```
import json
my_dict={'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}
my_json_string = json.dumps(my_dict)
resp_json=json.loads(my_json_string)
print(type(my_dict))
print(type(resp_json))
```

Output says : class 'dict' for both

But as menioned, I want to confirm if both are exactly the same thing, because I need to send back a JSON response and if both are exactly same, doesnt make sense to first convert it into a string using json.dumps() and then again do a json.loads() on it. I might as well return my dictionary object my_dict that I created. Hope my question is clear.

Comment: `print` only shows the string representation of the type, which I guess _might_ be misleading. Try `type(resp_json) == dict` and you see that it's actually _that_ `dict` type.

Comment: Both are same dictionaries

Comment: type(resp_json) == dict returns True

Comment: If your dictionary is the correct response why would you not just return it? They are not "exactly the same thing" (`resp_json is my_dict` returns `False`) but I don't see why that should matter.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "json object which is in dictionary format". `json.loads()` receives a string and iff it is a representation of a correct json object, it returns it's contents in a python dictionary, because they are similar/compatible types.

Comment: This will matter, since I will do a requests.post in the end where I need to send back a JSON only.

Comment: What do you mean by JSON here? JSON is text but both `resp_json` and `my_dict` are dictionaries and in this example they compare equal even if they are not the same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred way of validating/checking a python object's type is `isintance()`

```
isinstance(resp_json, type(my_dict))
```

I suspect however, that the misconception here is another.

As I pointed out in my comment, `json.loads()` returns a dictionary, iff a string representing syntactically correct JSON is passed. Therefor the type `dict` is correct, because this is python's built in way of representing key-value information in a similar way to how JS/JSON does.

If you want to know, whether they are the same object, i.e. stored in the same place in memory, you can use

```
  resp_json is my_dict
```

Judging by your question, however I suspect that what you are really interested in, is the equivalence of the contents.

```
resp_json == mydict
```

should give you this. I can't really immagine another scenario, which would mattter.

Comment: But this would return `True` even if the JSON dict were some special kind of dict, a subclass adding lots of additional information or functionality. IIUC, this is exactly what OP want's to find out.

Comment: It is returning 'True'

Comment: @MTTI Really like your detailed exlplanation. I would be sending back this response to requests.post(). As far as that goes, I think both will work same way, requests.post('',resp_json) or requests.post('',my_dict).

Comment: @UPCH I think this falls into the last category, where it doesn't matter and comparing simply adds computational overhead. If the answer helped you, please consider accepting it

Answer (score 2):

Both will be of type `dict`, but they are not the same dictionary, nor necessarily exactly equal.

For example, the json will contain unicode strings. In python 2, `my_dict` will not (it will str type). in this case `my_dict['key1']` is not exactly the same as `resp_json['key1']`.

As an aside, for most things pythonic, this difference should not matter and you might consider them the same. Still, it's important to keep in mind the possible differences and consider if you are dealing with an edge-case where it matters.

Comment: That is my hunch too, but I am not getting any way of validating the same. Both the checks -    type(resp_json) == dict and isinstance(resp_json, type(my_dict)) are returning True

Comment: @UPCH Here's an interactive example that shows what I said in python 2, the type of the keys and values is different: 
https://repl.it/repls/DodgerblueOddballKeyboardmapping

Comment: You are right about the unicode strings in Python 2, `resp_json` being `{u'key2': u'val2', u'key1': u'val1'}` but it's still equal `==` to `my_dict`.

Comment: @tobias_k, it all depends on which kind of quality are you looking for. Python being duck-typed usually anything that is dictionary-like should be good enough. But sometimes you might just be dealing with the edge-case that cares about the differences. And in this case, both are dictionaries in type. But maybe this the edge-case in which it matters if the content is the same type or not.

Comment: First, I am using Python3. Secondly, I wanted to check this since I am doing a requests.post('myurl',resp_json) at the end. Since I will be doing this in multiple places, want to make sure this doing json.dumps() and then json.loads() every time is really required or not.

Answer (score 1):

json module use this conversion table

https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json-to-py-table

```
+---------------+-----------+
|     JSON      |  Python   |
+---------------+-----------+
| object        | dict      |
| array         | list      |
| string        | unicode   |
| number (int)  | int, long |
| number (real) | float     |
| true          | True      |
| false         | False     |
| null          | None      |
+---------------+-----------+
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21582053)

Comment: @AlonsoDominguez i added ascii table. is it ok?